# Como juntar dois array

Tags: php, array

preciso juntar dois array 
primeiro array

```
array (size=11)
  7100 => boolean false
  7108 => boolean false
  7110 => boolean false
  7120 => boolean false
  7130 => boolean false
  7140 => boolean false
  7150 => boolean false
  7160 => boolean false
  7170 => boolean false
  7184 => boolean false
  7197 => boolean false
```

segundo array

```
array (size=11)
  7100 => 
    object(stdClass)[101]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7108 => 
    object(stdClass)[102]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7110 => 
    object(stdClass)[103]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7120 => 
    object(stdClass)[104]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7130 => 
    object(stdClass)[105]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7140 => 
    object(stdClass)[106]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7150 => 
    object(stdClass)[107]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7160 => 
    object(stdClass)[108]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7170 => 
    object(stdClass)[109]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7184 => 
    object(stdClass)[110]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
  7197 => 
    object(stdClass)[111]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
```

combinando ficaria assim.

exemplo com tamanho 1

```
7100 => 
    object(stdClass)[101]
      public 'qtdadulto' => int 0
      public 'qtdpintoumdia' => int 0
      public 'qtdovosferteis' => int 0
      (aqui a combinacao) public 'nome' => boolean false
```

Minhas tentativas

```
1º $combine = array_merge_recursive( $arResultado,$arraySaldo);
2º $arraycombine = array_combine($arResultado,$arraySaldo);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem objetos pode fazer um cast de StdClass para um array simples usando

```
$arr = (array) $lista;
```

Acredito que a forma mais simples seja fazer um foreach e verificar se a chave do primeiro array (`$arr`) existe no segundo, se sim cria uma nova chave chamada `nome` em `$arr`.

[Exemplo array - ideone](http://ideone.com/XbLTws)

```
<?php

$arr = [
        7100 => [
                    'qtdadulto' =>  0,
                    'qtdpintoumdia' => 0,
                    'qtdovosferteis' =>0
                ],
        7108 => [
                    'qtdadulto' => 0,
                    'qtdpintoumdia' =>0,
                    'qtdovosferteis' => 0
                ],
        7110 => [
                    'qtdadulto' => 0,
                    'qtdpintoumdia' => 0,
                    'qtdovosferteis' =>  0
                    ]
];

$arr2 = [7100 => 1, 7108 => 200, 7110 => 500, 800 => 99];


foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(isset($arr2[$k])){
        $arr[$k]['nome'] = $arr2[$k];
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [7100] => Array
        (
            [qtdadulto] => 0
            [qtdpintoumdia] => 0
            [qtdovosferteis] => 0
            [nome] => 1
        )

    [7108] => Array
        (
            [qtdadulto] => 0
            [qtdpintoumdia] => 0
            [qtdovosferteis] => 0
            [nome] => 200
        )

    [7110] => Array
        (
            [qtdadulto] => 0
            [qtdpintoumdia] => 0
            [qtdovosferteis] => 0
            [nome] => 500
        )

)
```

Comment: Acabei fazendo o foreach mesmo.

Comment: Existe o array_map que resolve esses casos

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o array_map, ele aplica a função de callback para cada elemento do array Ex:

```
$resultMerge = array_map(function($a,$b){ $b->nome = $a; return $b; },$array1,$array2);
```

Se quiser deixar mais legível o código dá para fazer:

```
function setItemArray($a, $b){ 
    $b->nome = $a; 
    return $b;
}

$resultMerge = array_map("setItemArray",$array1,$array2);
```

Ou chamar o array_map direto, visto que é alterado o array passado como paramêtro.

```
 array_map("setItemArray",$array1,$array2);
```

Referência: [array_map PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)